# Laravel/Eloquent - Querying report cards according to current user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My current project is a school management system. Right now, I need to do the following:

- Query the database to get all report cards associated with the current user;
- Display them in a view;

Main main problem is the first part, since I am a beginner in Eloquent. I believe I can use blade to construct tables to display the information from the report cards -- provided I can pass that information on using a controller.

I have established the association between `users` and `cards` using hasMany and belogsTo as per Eloquent's documentation. In my CardController I have the following:

```
class CardController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {

    $card = App\User::find(1)->cards;

    // After querying, return the view, etc
  }
}
```

The function is missing functionality, but I don't know exactly what. I have tried some other things, such as:

```
  $cards = DB::table('cards')->get();

  return view('viewname');
```

There's something basic I'm missing here, I know, but I can't put my finger on it. To be perfectly honest, I'm still not comfortable querying databases in Laravel even after reading the most of the documentation.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're saying that you've established the relationship between both models, half of the work is done, 
First I can see that you're not retrieving the currently authenticated user, which is who I believe you want to retrieve the report cards for in the view, to do that you can simply put this in your index method:

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

but now I encourage you to go to **tinker**, `php artisan tinker` in the terminal and try this:

```
$user = App\User::first(); // or change this to App\User::find($someId);
$cards = $user->cards;
```

And check the output, the thing is, this `$user->cards`the word **cards** should be identical to the method name you defined on the User model, so it should be something like this in your `User.php`:

```
public function cards() {
    return $this->hasMany(Card::class);
}
```

So now you should have a collection of the available cards for this user,
your `index` method should look like this:

```
   public function index() {
       $user = auth()->user();
       $cards = $user->cards;
       // Or you can inline it and make it all in one line like this,
       // $cards = auth()->user()->cards;

       return view('someView', compact('cards'));
   }
```

And in your `someView.blade.php`, just loop over them, something like this:

```
@foreach ($cards as $card)
    {{ $card->someProperty }}
@endforeach
```

Hopefully this helps, let me know if you need something else.

Comment: To be sure there is nothing wrong with the `$user->cards` implicit model loading, try an explicit load with `$user->load('cards')` right before using the relation. The relation name must match the function name, obviously.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :) Typing `$user = auth()->user();` on the tinker interface returns `null`. Both commands result in the error "Trying to get property of non-object on line 2".

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, honest mistake, I updated the answer, since tinker doesn't know who's the authenticated user is, I was just trying to make you see the output yourself in tinker, but yeah type it as it was originally in your question and it will be fine, but in the code itself in your index.php method, change it to $user = auth()->user(); and it should work there.